# Magento 2: Paypal Express not returning Billing Address back to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, paypal-express, billing-address

I'd been having issues with Paypal, where the Billing Address is not returned back to Magento 2 after making a transaction through Paypal. Instead in the Order details from the admin and the Order Confirmation email, the Shipping Address is returned as the Billing Address.

I have debugged, enabled "Require Customer's Billing Address" and even updated to Magento 2.1.7 with no solution.

I have been facing the issue since Magento 2.1.2.

Comment: What kind of checkout did you try: from a mini cart, guest checkout, checkout from payment page? By default, the billing address always the same as shipping, in a case, if billing address is not provided, for example, guest checkout - it will be retrieved from PayPal. Also, `Require Customer's Billing Address` should be enabled for a merchant account by PayPal support.

Comment: Hi @jonijones Paypal is on the Payment page and it happens on both the guest checkout and when a user is logged in.

Comment: I've checked on 2.1.9 and for a guest customer, the billing address is provided by PayPal.

Comment: Hi @jonijones would you mind pointing me to the part of the source code on Magento 2, where you found this?

Comment: Hi, what exactly you need?

Comment: @jonijones so I found this link in which you mentioned https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10541 setting up `Billing Address On` to Payment Page could set the correct behavior that I am looking. where the Billing Address would be different than the shipping if I specify it from the Magento 2 site is that correct?

Comment: Yes, in that case, the billing address would be different.